# How to get current Location in ArcGis map In android using Imagery Map server

Tags: android, arcgis, currentlocation

I am working In an app to develop a custom ArcGis map. I am able to show the map using base map url. I am using following fragment of code

```
mapView.addLayer(new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
            "http://maps.ocparks.com/arcgis/rest/services/Imagery/2013_Imagery/MapServer"));
```

As this map shows a particular region (orange county). now i want to get current location and show on this map. is there any way to do this? after going through several docs of ArcGis I just came to kmow that to show current location the url of base map should be --

```
http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer
```

but for imagery map server how to show current location. if any one know please help me

Comment: I don't believe that the URL is the root cause of your issue. Acutally, both URLs are map servers being added as a layer and. Are you able to get current location working with `http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer`?

Comment: yes ... with world_street_map I am able to get my current location

Comment: but with this imagery map server location is not getting

Comment: it may be because of imagery server lot belonging to your current location?

Comment: What is the coordinates of your current location?

Comment: i am using---- LocationDisplayManager ls = map.getLocationDisplayManager();
  ls.setLocationListener(new MyLocationListener());
  ls.start();
  //ls.setAutoPan(false);
  ls.setAutoPanMode(AutoPanMode.LOCATION);

Comment: in location listener's onLocationChange() method I am getting location

Comment: My guess would be something related with spacial references or coordinate systems. It would add your location to a map position where there is no image from `http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer`. If you are not satisfied with the answer you got, you can debug the application and get the coordinates (for instance X:Y or latitude:longitude), the spacial reference and the coordinate system. With this, we could see if is that your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till now it is not possible , may be using javascript it can be done.
for getting current location we should use World_Street_Map as a base layer

Comment: Although I have developed a lot of android applications in the past and currently I'm a ArcGIS developer, I have never developed an ArcGIS client for android. That said, It makes no sense to me current location works for one URL but not for another. Maps services will just delivery images (like .png) and what you suggest would be like _it can add current location to 'yellow image' but not to a 'red image''_. Anyway, I believe you know more about this API than I.